# Ubuntu won't run

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

So I just installed it last night, the latest version. I did a fresh install.

When I woke this morning I turn on the computer and login. It goes to a black screen with two thick with/multicolored lines towards the bottom and freezes. I then must shut down the tower. I have only been able to run the 'Ubuntu 2D' option.

I am new to this all and need some help.

Also when I am using terminal it wants me to enter my password, but it says its incorrect. Is there anyway so I don't need to enter my password when I use it and also when I install or remove something?

Many thanks would be helpful.

What is Ubuntu 2D?

Comment: Are you sure that your graphic card is good enough?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information if you want someone to help.

Computer make and model

What CPU

How much RAM memory

What graphics board or chip

BTW Ubuntu 2D or Unity 2d is a version of the Desktop used for graphics cards with no 3D acceleration or not enougn memory to use it (often the case in untweaked virtual machines)